# Date format VBA (versus Date format in Excel sheet)

Tags: excel, vba, date-format

I want to use a date (which is specified in a cell F2 = 01/11/2022) in a filter:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("QuotationOverview").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:= xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, "11-2022")
```

As you can see I now have the date (month), hard coded "11-2022" but if I change that into Range("F2") the sorting is applied on January 2022. The VBA code expects the format mm/dd/YYYY but the format in Excel is dd/mm/YYYY.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("QuotationOverview").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:= xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, Range("F2"))
```

How can I inform VBA that the format is dd/mm/YYYY and not mm/dd/YYYY?

Comment: `11-2022` isn't a date because it lacks a day of month. Dates have no format either in Excel or VBA, they're binary values. Formats apply *only* when parsing text into a date, or formatting a date into text. When you enter a date into a cell it's actually saved as an OLE Automation Date (OADate) which is essentially a float whose integral part is an offset sinse `1899-12-31` and the fractional part represents the time of day

Comment: When you select a Mont/Year style for a cell, Excel *still* saves a full date, eg `2022-10-01` but displays only the month and year. That's what allows date functions to work with that value. In VBA you can construct a date with `DateSerial(2022,10,1)` and pass it as an argument anywhere you want to use a date.

Comment: If `Criteria2` expects strings though, you still have to specify a full date, ie including the date, using the US date format. This will be translated into a VBA `Date` value, no matter the user's locale or the cell style of individual cells

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Format` to generate your *month-year* text values:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("QuotationOverview").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:= xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, Format(Range("F2"),"mm-yyyy"))
```